# How can I grant a user group permission to start/stop a custom service?

Tags: permissions, systemd, chmod, systemctl, chgrp

I have a service that exists in the root directory and I want to give user group admin permissions to run the service.

The service exists in `/root/home/custom_service/service.service`

I tried `chgrp admin ./home/custom_service/` then `chmod g+rx ./home/custom_service/`

When I check the permissions with `ls -l ./home/custom_service/` I get `-rw-r-xr-- 1 root admin  449 May 30 11:23 service.service`

When I try and run the service from my testUsr account (which is in the group admin) this is the result:

I ran:

```
systemctl start service.service
```

Result:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: scarycall
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Permission denied
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start service.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status service.service' for details.
```

Note: I am able to run the service from root.

---

UPDATE:

Here is my polkit rule file:

```
Array.prototype.includes = function(variable) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { if (this[i] === variable) { return true; } }
    return false;
}

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    var allowed = {
        units: [
            // Here you can add units that you want to allow admin users to manage.
            "service.service"
        ],
        actions: [
            "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units"
        ],
        verbs: [
            "start", "stop", "restart"
        ]
    }
    var unit_name = action.lookup("unit");
    
    polkit.log("Action" + action);
    polkit.log("Unit=" + unit_name);
    polkit.log("Action ID=" + action.id);
    polkit.log("Verb=" + action.lookup("verb"));
    polkit.log("Subject=" + subject);
    
    if (allowed.actions.includes(action.id) &&
        allowed.units.includes(unit_name) &&
        allowed.verbs.includes(action.lookup("verb")) &&
        subject.isInGroup("admin")
    ) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

The system I am running on has systemd version 219 which does not pass unit or verb through the action. Here is what the logs from this rule look like:

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-insight-service.rules:23: Action[Action id='org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-insight-service.rules:24: Unit=undefined
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-insight-service.rules:25: Action ID=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-insight-service.rules:26: Verb=undefined
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-insight-service.rules:27: Subject=[Subject pid=13762 user='testUsr' groups=admin seat='' session='2072' local=false active=true]
```

The unit and verb details were not added until v226 seen here:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/88ced61bf9673407f4b15bf51b1b408fd78c149d

**RESOLUTION:**
Because the system I am running on runs an older version of systemd it does not support the unit or verb details of action. So I resolved to use sudo permissions and that worked.

In the sudoer file I added:

```
%admin ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start service.service
%admin ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop service.service
%admin ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart service.service
%admin ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl status service.service
```

Comment: Why do you not use the default systemd path for service files?

Comment: The system I am working on and the requirements I have to work in mean I have to have the service files outside of the default

Comment: What is your OS and systemd version?

Comment: Instead of adding the resolution to your original question, you should post it as an answer and accept it as the actual answer for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Polkit policy that allows users in the `admin` group to start, stop or restart specific system units. For example.

```javascript
// Allow user in admin group to manage specific systemd units
Array.prototype.includes = function(variable) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { if (this[i] === variable) { return true; } }
    return false;
}

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    var allowed = {
        units: [
            // Here you can add units that you want to allow admin users to manage.
            "backup.service",
            "nginx.service",
            "backup-rotate.service"
        ],
        actions: [
            "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files"
        ],
        verbs: [
            "start", "stop", "restart"
        ]
    }
    var unit_name = action.lookup("unit");
    if (allowed.actions.includes(action.id) &&
        allowed.units.includes(unit_name) &&
        allowed.verbs.includes(action.lookup("verb")) &&
        subject.isInGroup("admin")
    ) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

Save the policy file as `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/60-units.rules`, the new rule should take effect immediately.

Comment: So the rule file name would be 60-units.rules

Comment: Yes, I made a typo, the name of the rule files is irrelevant, but it's common practice to prefix them with a number.

Comment: is the vi: ft=javascript comment required? Is it marking the file type like #!/bin/bash?

Comment: I've added the file and saved it but the error remains the same - the authentication message still appears the same and is authenticating as 'scarycall' still

Comment: The rule file is an example, did you change the `allowed.unites` array? If not, you should append the name of the desired service to this array.

Comment: I updated allowed units? Also when I polkit.log() the unit_name it is undefined, as is action.lookup("verb")

Comment: My systemctl version does not have access to unit or verb so those undefined values seem to be the break case here

Comment: If your unit is called `service.service`, add it to the `units` array of the `allowed` object. `action.lookup` is a polkit built-in method. And `unit_name` is defined in this rule. What is your OS and polkit version? Also what is the rule file you using now? Please post it.

Comment: >>> My systemctl version does not have access to unit or verb <<< What does that mean? Please clarify,

Comment: And if you have read the rules file, your account will need to be added to the admin group if it is not already.

Comment: I updated the original post with the polkit file and what the logs return

Comment: It is `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files` **not** `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units`.

Comment: Based on the action id output by the log it is `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units`

Comment: There are two actions here, `manage-unit-files` `manage-units` does not allow you to enable/disable the service. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html

Comment: >>> Based on the action id output by the log <<< Please note that there are two separate logs because the rule file is called twice.