# Polkit rule not working

Tags: permissions, systemd, systemctl, polkit

My pkaction version is 0.112

I have a service that exists in the root directory and I want to give user group admin permissions to run the service.

The service exists in `/root/home/custom_service/service.service`

I tried `chgrp admin ./home/custom_service/` then `chmod g+rx ./home/custom_service/`

When I check the permissions with `ls -l ./home/custom_service/` I get `-rw-r-xr-- 1 root admin  449 May 30 11:23 service.service`

When I try and run the service from my testUsr account (which is in the group admin) this is the result:

I ran:

```
systemctl start service.service
```

Result:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: scarycall
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Permission denied
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start service.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status service.service' for details.
```

Note: I am able to run the service from root.

So I enabled a polkit rule as follows

```
// vi: ft=javascript
// Allow user in admin group to manage specific systemd units
Array.prototype.includes = function(variable) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) { if (this[i] === variable) { return true; } }
    return false;
}

polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    var allowed = {
        units: [
            "service.service"
        ],
        actions: [
            "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files"
        ],
        verbs: [
            "start", "stop", "restart"
        ]
    }
    var unit_name = action.lookup("unit");
    if (allowed.actions.includes(action.id) &&
        allowed.units.includes(unit_name) &&
        allowed.verbs.includes(action.lookup("verb")) &&
        subject.isInGroup("admin")
    ) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});
```

This is saved at `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/60-service.rules`

This rule did not work when I reran 'systemctl start service.service` I still got the result listed above.

**UPDATE:**
The system I am running on does not have the right version of systemd to support the unit and verb details of action. So I had to use sudo permissions instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I grant a user group permission to start/stop a custom service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750516/how-can-i-grant-a-user-group-permission-to-start-stop-a-custom-service)

Comment: For starting and stopping a service you need `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units` instead of `org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files`. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html Search for `Operations which modify unit state`